# Cloudinary thumbnail creation for assets

Tags: filesystem

I realized Craft 3 generates its own thumbnails and does not use Cloudinary to do this on the CP. My question is, how and where should I modify the JavaScript code, or what is the best practice to use external generator.

What I would like to do is really just utilize the query string of Cloudinary instead of doing this on Craft side...?

So somehow I would like to overwrite this call, and change it:

```
SITE/cpresources/4c875891/thumb-30x30.jpg?v=1522966431
```

And I also would like to avoid the generate thumbnail:

```
http://tr3nds.test/index.php?p=admin/actions/assets/generate-thumb&uid=7b78d4ed-9c3d-4193-89c0-f20e0d3c35be&width=30&height=30&v=1523244927
```

Comment: FWIW, it's something that's on my "to do" list to write a Cloudinary driver for ImageOptimize: https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-imageoptimize/issues/10 -- if interested, voice your support in the thread. Then you'd be able to just choose "Cloudinary" as your transform method, and it'd "just work" everywhere, like it does not with Imgix.

Comment: If you want to use ImageOptimize with Cloudinary, install the [Cloudinary](https://github.com/timkelty/craft3-cloudinary) plugin that will make Cloudinary available as a file system for Craft CMS 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch the `EVENT_GET_ASSET_THUMB_URL` event in your plugin and return the `$event->url`:

```
   Event::on(Assets::class, Assets::EVENT_GET_ASSET_THUMB_URL, function(GetAssetThumbUrlEvent $event) {
            $event->url = $this->thumbUrl($event);
        });

   protected function thumbUrl($event)
      {
           return "{$this->cloudinary_ulr}/image/upload/w_{$event->width},h_{$event->height}/{$event->asset->filename}";
      }
```